# C# DLL used by ActiveX - Can you return Javascript arrays?

Tags: c#, dll, com, activex

I've managed to cobble together a C# DLL that can be loaded via ActiveX in IE9 (don't worry, this is for personal use only). I can return strings and booleans just fine, but when trying to return an array, `typeof` returns the type as `unknown`. I tried using an array (`return new string[0]`), a List, and I also tried returning an array like this: `Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 0)`. All of these resulted in the type being `unknown`.

Now, I know I can use `JavaScriptSerializer` to convert the array to a JSON string, and then just use `JSON.parse` from IE9 to convert it to a Javascript array, but I'm wondering, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I searched and saw that accepted answer, which suggests to use JSON strings, and skipped right over it. I should've read the next answer which explains exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to award you points for this or is it preferred that I just close this question?

Comment: Yeah, the gold isn't always the accepted answer. You're welcome.

Comment: If you can close it accepting the duplicate, that might be best since it will become a "signpost" to the correct answer.